# angularjs + ui-router + gulp-uglify

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, angular-ui-router, gulp-uglify

Всё работает до момента переименования переменных при минимизации ...

**1)** Когда заходим в корень приложения http://localhost:8080/, вылетает ошибка `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

```
App.config([

'$stateProvider',
'$urlRouterProvider',
'$locationProvider',
'localStorageServiceProvider',

function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, localStorageServiceProvider) {

    _log('App config ...');

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    localStorageServiceProvider
        .setPrefix('SA');

    localStorageServiceProvider
        .setStorageType('localStorage');


    $urlRouterProvider
        .when('/', '/stat')
        .when('/stat/','/stat')
        .otherwise("/404");

}]);
```

Наблюдателей за состоянием и прямого его изменения в приложении нет.

Для проверки добавил:

```
var App = angular.module("app", [

    'app.auth', 'app.stat',
    'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router',
    'LocalStorageModule', 'ngAnimate',
    'angularMoment'

]).run([

    '$rootScope', '$state',
    '$stateParams', 'amMoment',

    function($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, amMoment) {

        _log('App run ...');

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
            function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options) {
                _log('$stateChangeStart: ', arguments);
        });

        amMoment.changeLocale('ru');

        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

    }
]);
```

по этому и вижу, что $stateChangeStart отрабатывает 5 раз и выдаёт ошибку ...

**2)** Если я захожу или обновляю страницу  http://localhost:8080/stat

Везде строго придерживаюсь стиля

```
['inject1', 'inject2', function(inject1, inject2) { /* somecode */ }]
```

Никаких ошибок в консолях FF и Chrome нет.

при `uglify({ mangle: false })` всё работает ...

Ошибка:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
minErr/<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:68:12
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:16133:1
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:16359:13
done@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:10791:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:10989:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:10930:1
@chrome://firebug/content/lib/wrapper.js:112:43
consoleLog/<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:12722:18
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:9490:7
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:16361:13
done@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:10791:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:10989:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:10930:1
@debugger eval code:1:1
consoleLog/<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:12722:18
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:9490:7
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:16361:13
bootstrapApply@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:1680:9
invoke@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:4535:14
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:1678:1
bootstrap@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:1698:1
angularInit@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:1592:5
@http://localhost:8080/libs/angular/angular.js?1455281609647:29652:5
n.Callbacks/j@http://localhost:8080/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?1455281609647:2:26920
n.Callbacks/k.fireWith@http://localhost:8080/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?1455281609647:2:27738
.ready@http://localhost:8080/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?1455281609647:2:29530
I@http://localhost:8080/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js?1455281609647:2:29721
```

$stateChangeStart:

```
Object { name="$stateChangeStart",  targetScope=Scope,  defaultPrevented=false,  ещё...}
Object { templateUrl="pages/stat/list/template.html",  controller="statListCtrl",  name="stat.list",  url="" }
Object {}
Object { url="^",  abstract=true,  name="",  views=null }
Object {}
Object { location=false,  inherit=true,  notify=true,  ещё...}
```

Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: попробуйте убрать: `.when('/stat/','/stat')`

Comment: кроме того после непосредственно текста ошибки идет еще описание или стек, добавьте его в вопрос тоже

Comment: @Grundy, пробовал, делу не помогает. Сейчас стек добавлю

Comment: и было бы не плохо еще с какими аргументами 5 раз вызывается $stateChangeStart

Comment: @Grundy, аргументыа всегд одинаковые.

Comment: похоже что ошибка может быть в сопутствующем коде, можете выбросить все контроллеры и модули, либо закомментировать их содержимое и попробовать с пустыми запустить?

Comment: @Grundy, всё выкинул, вообще ... https://jsfiddle.net/L8vhpLk7/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35643/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexey-lemesh).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The `resolve` property is a map object**

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Не работает:

```
resolve: [ '$q', '$rootScope', function(a, b) { /* code */ } ]
```

Работает:

```
resolve: { "data": [ '$q', '$rootScope', function(a, b) { /* code */ } ]}
```

Angular воспринимает параметр resolve как объект, и читает его как пару "ключ": "значение"/"обещание". В первом варианте, при минификации, сервисы просто теряются.

Comment: посмотри во что он минифицирует это все

Comment: @Grundy, построчно изменял минифицированый файл ...